# JSONModel - can't assign fetched JSON to model like the tutorial

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, jsonmodel

I try to store JSON like this tutorial

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/

In the tutorial it declare LocationModel in LoanModel.h.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) LocationModel* location;
```

Which work great in the projectDemo but when I try to use it in my project like this

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) ContentDetailModel *content;
```

It will return null.

It will work after I delete that line.

So can you guy check my code to see where is it wrong?

Here is JSON data that i try to fetch

```
{

"status": "success",

"content": [
    {
        "id": 11447,
        "title": "Arsenal's Afobe targets a full season on loan",
        "dateTime": "30.10.2014 06:38",
        "tags": [],
        "content": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "subject": "Benik Afobe",
                "description": "The 21-year-old was last capped by the Three Lions in February 2013 when he featured for the Under-21s against Sweden at Walsall in a 4-0 win.\r\n\r\nA series of injuries since then have restricted his progress both on the club and international front and he spent the second half of last season on loan at Sheffield Wednesday."
            }
        ],
        "ingress": "Arsenal and England Under-21s striker Afobe is hoping a full season on loan can help to rejuvenate his career.\r\n",
        "image": "http://87.251.89.41/sites/default/files/afobe-celeb-dier.jpg",
        "created": 1407476424,
        "changed": 1414664497
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my model in ContentListModel.h

```
@protocol ContentListModel

@end

@interface ContentListModel : JSONModel

@property (assign,nonatomic) NSString * id;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * title;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * dateTime;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray  * tags;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * ingress;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * image;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * created;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *changed;

@property(strong,nonatomic) ContentDetailModel *content;

@end
```

Here is my model in ContentDetailModel.h

```
@interface ContentDetailModel : JSONModel

@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString * type;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString * subject;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString * description;

@end
```

Here is FOTTFeed.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "ContentListModel.h"

@interface FOTTFeed : JSONModel

@property (strong , nonatomic) NSArray<ContentListModel> *content;

@end
```

Here is my code

```
#import "FeedList.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "JSONModelLib.h"
#import "FOTTFeed.h"
#import "HUD.h"
#import "FeedDetail.h"

@interface FeedList (){
    FOTTFeed *feed;
}

@end

@implementation FeedList{
    NSArray *tableData;

}
@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize detailView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    _menu.target = self.revealViewController;
    _menu.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

    //background image
    UIImage * background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_2.jpg"];
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:background];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:imageView];




    //set navigation bar colour
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(29/255.0) green:(43/255.0) blue:(58/255.0) alpha:1.0]];

}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Loading..."];

    //fetch the feed
    feed = [[FOTTFeed alloc]initFromURLWithString:@"http://87.251.89.41/application/11424/article/get_articles_list" completion:^(JSONModel * model, JSONModelError *err){



        //hide the loader view
        [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];

        //json fetch
       NSLog(@"Content:%@",feed.content);

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{



    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [feed.content count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell setOpaque:NO];
    [cell setBackgroundColor: [UIColor clearColor]];


    ContentListModel *data = [feed.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImageView *thumbnailImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *titleNews = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    UILabel *Time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:300];
    UITextView * ingress = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:400];

    ingress.editable = false;

    titleNews.text = data.title;


    ingress.text = data.ingress;


    Time.text = data.dateTime;



    [thumbnailImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data.image]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"]];


    return cell;

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showFeedDetail"]){
        NSIndexPath *indexpath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        FeedDetail *detailView = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailView.data = [feed.content objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];


    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You haven't posted any actual code, just some interface declarations.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the reply. I edit my post already.

Comment: Except you left out the import part. Where's the code that does the JSON parsing and where's the code that should set the `content` property?

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry. i edit my post already.

Comment: No, that's not the correct code. It's the code of `FOTTFeed` that you are having a problem with, correct? Didn't you say that the `content` property is `nil`?

Comment: @rmaddy It has only a model. thank for being patient with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Detail is an array:

```
"content": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "subject": "Benik Afobe",
            "description": "The 21-year-old was last capped by the Three Lions in February 2013 when he featured for the Under-21s against Sweden at Walsall in a 4-0 win.\r\n\r\nA series of injuries since then have restricted his progress both on the club and international front and he spent the second half of last season on loan at Sheffield Wednesday."
        }
    ]
```

In your model ContentListModel, the "content" property, I think, shoud be a NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

[BWJSONMatcher](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher/) is a lightweight library which helps you easily match a JSON string or JSON object up with your data model. If all properties of your data models are consistent with the keys in json data, **BWJSONMatcher** will automatically match them up.

You can find the detailed examples [here](https://github.com/BurrowsWang/BWJSONMatcher/tree/master/BWJSONMatcherTests) .